# Как делать, чтоб при нажатии рандомно нажимался другая кнопка

Tags: java, android

Например у меня есть button1 - button 9, и хочу делать так, чтоб при нажатии на button1 рандомно нажимался например button 2, button 3 или button 4.....

Comment: Вам достаточно знать про симуляцию нажатия

Answer (score 6):

Сохраняете все кнопки например в `List<Button> buttons`, а потом из списка выбираете случайную

```
int currentButtonIndex = 3; //Должно определяться в функции onClick нажатой кнопки
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(buttons.size());
if(randomIndex == currentButtonIndex){
 randomIndex = randomIndex+1 % buttons.size();
}

buttons.get(randomIndex).performClick();
```